# Flask script windows subprocess and sys

Tags: python, flask

I have the following Ptyhon Flask script,

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "index"

@app.route("/script")
def cmd():
    cmd = [sys.executable, "C:\\Users\\JSm\\Project\\FlaskAutomation\\test.py"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    out = p.communicate()
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run()
```

The cmd() command works outside of the flask app when run independently, however it is crashing now. Any suggestions as to why?

I am running this on a windows machine, I want to kick off a script from a Python Flask script

Any help much appreciated. 
Thanks,
J

Comment: What do you mean by crashing? Is it giving you 500 error? Can you please mention version of Python?

Comment: Does "crashing" really mean "crashing the python interpreter"? Do any errors get thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure about windows environment, however if i use the same script and assuming i've `test.py` is present at given location, I get 500 internal server error if i go and access `/script`.

To make it successful, I've made following change,

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```